# Why do I have to call Repaint during OnMouseMove?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, repaint

In my Delphi / C++Builder app, I have an OnMouseMove handler that lets the user interact with a plot by dragging plot elements.  (We've manually implemented the necessary drag-and-drop logic instead of using the VCL's OnDragOver et al.)

The OnMouseMove event updates both the main form and several child forms based on the current state of the plot.  However, as long as I'm moving the mouse, neither the main form nor any of the child forms actually redraw their updated state unless I manually call Repaint on the form and each of its child forms.  This is somewhat fragile, since it's easy to miss a child form that needs to be repainted.

The instant I stop moving the mouse, the forms repaint as expected, so it appears that controls are being invalidated as expected, they're just not getting repainted as long as OnMouseMove events / WM_MOUSEMOVE messages are coming in.  (If I drag *very* slowly, then the screen will also repaint as expected.)

Even manually calling Repaint on each form isn't always enough, because individual child forms' controls may not redraw unless I repaint them individually.  (For example, a TEdit displays its new value if I call its parent TForm's Repaint, but a TRadioButton that I disable doesn't appear disabled unless I call its own Repaint.)

Why is it necessary to call Repaint at all?  Why isn't Windows automatically repainting my app's windows while I drag the mouse?  Is there a better way of redrawing windows than trying to manually enumerate which windows need to have Repaint called?

From playing around with a brief test application, I'm wondering if the problem is that my OnMouseMove event is slow enough that WM_PAINT messages don't get dispatched because the application is too busy with WM_MOUSEMOVE?  I'm not sure if this is indeed the case or, if so, what to do about this.

Here's some (hopefully not overly simplified) code to illustrate what I'm doing.  GraphArea is a TImage whose Canvas contains the plot.

```
void __fastcall TMachineForm::GraphAreaMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if (IsNearAdjustableObject(X, Y)) {
        is_adjusting = true;
    }
}

void TMachineForm::GraphAreaMouseMove(TObject *Sender,
    TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if (is_adjusting) {
        AdjustObject(X, Y);

        /* Draws to the GraphArea TImage by calling GraphArea->Canvas methods */
        RedrawGraphArea();

        /* Updates several standard VCL controls on ChildForm1 and ChildForm2;
         * e.g., ChildForm1->Edit1->Text = CalculatedValue(); */
        NotifyChildForm1OfAdjustment();
        NotifyChildForm2OfAdjustment();

        /* This is where I have to manually call Repaint. I don't know why. */
        GraphArea->Repaint();
        ChildForm1->Repaint();
        ChildForm2->Repaint();
    }
}

void TMachineForm::GraphAreaMouseUp(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    is_adjusting = false;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it's because drag operations run inside a special message loop rather akin to a modal message loop.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Even though I'm manually implementing my own drag-and-drop from an OnMouseMove handler instead of invoking any VCL drag operations?

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing anything about your manual implementation of drag and drop. Normally, you don't have to call `Repaint` (and shouldn't be in the first place - `Invalidate` on the parent control is usually enough to update it and it's child controls).

Comment: Well, I assume you meant that you were calling `Repaint` because `Invalidate` was no good. If you are custom drawing on your window I'd expect you to be using `InvalidateRect` to ensure that all regions affected by a drag get an opportunity to paint themselves. In the version of the code that doesn't call `Repaint`, what do you call? Showing code would mean we would not have to guess at what you are doing. Remember, we can't see your screen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I realized I left out some detail, so I've added and and some sample code.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Still not really enough code. Not obvious why the code before the 3 `Repaint` calls would result in a paint cycle. Also, don't you need to capture the mouse to make sure that you always receive the `MouseUp`. It could well be that the mouse move events are processed more slowly than they are posted and so WM_PAINT never gets processed. Remember that WM_PAINT is a low priority event and so the queue must be empty before it will be processed. What happens if you drag slowly?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Apparently the VCL automatically captures the mouse (as seen by the TMouse Capture property), so I don't have to.  I've updated my sample code to explain what the code before `Repaint` does; it's drawing to the GraphArea TImage and updating a bunch of standard controls' properties.  If I draw very slowly, the screen repaints as expected.

Comment: I think you have your answer then. Call Update to force the paint cycle.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, I do know that. But you can call Update on the form and only those controls that have been invalidated need to be repainted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Raymond Chen explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/19/10249000.aspx) how WM_PAINT messages work.  Invalidating a window (whether by setting VCL methods or properties that cause the window to be invalidated, or manually, by calling `Invalidate`) effectively causes a flag to be set saying that a `WM_PAINT` message should be delivered the next time `GetMessage` is called and no messages are available.

As far as I can tell, if messages are being generated fast enough (for example, the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages) and processing these messages is taking long enough, then the message queue may never be empty, so `WM_PAINT` messages are never delivered.

The solution is to manually call `Update` (which should perform a bit better than `Repaint`) or similar.  Additional considerations:

- Repainting all owned forms: I haven't found a clean solution here, so I'll probably continue manually tracking owned forms and manually invoking Repaint on them.  (If I wanted, I can iterate over the TForm's Components looking for TForms, but that adds measurable overhead.)
- Handling child controls (such as the TRadioButton that doesn't redraw itself as disabled in my example): Instead of calling `Repaint` or `Update`, use [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can instruct child windows to redraw themselves as well.

  ```
  RedrawWindow(ChildForm1->Handle, NULL, NULL,
      RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
  ```

Comment: Update would only perform a bit better than Repaint if you are only invalidating parts of your window (not the entire surface as with Invalidate).

Answer (score 4):

Once, I noticed the same behaviour in my application where I use VCL drag and drop. Somehow the `WM_PAINT` messages resulting from posting themselves or calling `Invalidate` do not get to the top of the message queue.

Instead of `Repaint`, I suggest using `Update` which should deal with child repainting better.

Answer (score 2):

`Repaint()` performs an immediate re-paint of the control it is called on.  Chances are that your adjustment logic is making changes to the GraphicArea and ChildForms ina way that require them to redraw themselves with new values, but they do not actually know that they need to be redrawn so they do not do so.  That would explain why you are not seeing any changes unless you trigger repaints manually.

I would suggest using `Invalidate()` instead of `Repaint()`.  `Invalidate()` signals to the OS that the control needs to be repainted, but does not actually perform the painting yet.  This lets the OS manage the painting on its own time, and the controls will receive paint requests from the OS normally instead of from you directly.

Comment: `Invalidate()` doesn't help, apparently because the mouse messages are coming in too fast for the OS to ever deliver the `WM_PAINT` requests.

Comment: You could call each control's `Update()` method to process pending paint requests one at a time, or you could call the Form's `Update()` method by itself to process all pending paint requests for the Form and children at one time.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to manually list every form and control that needs updating; that seems hard to maintain.  As I tried to explain in my question, calling the form's `Update` repaints some but not all children.  (`RedrawWindow` can correctly repaint all children if desired.)